# Upgrade helm using ansible playbook in kubernetes namespace

Tags: ansible, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to upgrade helm with `helm upgrade` in kubernetes cluster using Ansible.

I have 10 different namespaces. I have written Ansible playbook get all 10 namespaces, after that we have to upgrade helm using helm upgrade command in 10 names automatically, here I am not able to that activity. May I know how can we do that?

Comment: Can you have more details on what you are not able to do?
Is it just the loop over the namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear to me. Anyway, as far as I understand you were able to collect the all your namespaces (I assume that you have stored this in ansible variable called `namespaces_list`). And you are now stuck, to loop on that list to run the different helm updates…

```
- name: Update helm chart
  helm:
    host: localhost
    chart:
      name: …
      …
    state: present
    name: …
    namespace: "{{ namespace }}"
    loop: "{{ namespaces_list }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: namespace
```